# How to get rid of this weird spike on the mesh?

Tags: mesh

I'm making a helmet and when I finished it, there wasn't any issue. But when I applied Subdivision and Solidify modifiers, this spike and this weird edge popped up, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Here [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vVS4GE11" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vVS4GE11/)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the subdivided faces were protuding in that case but put the *Solidify* modifier above the *Subdivision* Surface, it's the way the modifiers should be ordered most of the times and in you case it fixes your problem